# how to display result of query

Tags: php, mysql

After query I try to display data. I can receive only data from 'field_1[]'. From 'field_2[]' and from 'field[]' no. How to fix it?

```
if (!$result) {    
die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}

$fields_num = mysql_num_rows($result);

//------------------------------------------------------------------    
for($i_1=0; $i_1<$fields_num; $i_1++)
{    
$field_1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);    
echo "<td>a".$field_1['index_period_1']."</td>";
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------

for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)
{    
$field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);    
echo "<td>b".$field['index_period']."</td>";
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------    
for($i_2=0; $i_2<$fields_num; $i_2++)
{    
$field_2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);    
echo "<td>c".$field_2['index_period_2']."</td>";
}
```

edit:----------------------

```
|------------|period_1  |period_1  |period_1  |
-----------------------------------------------
|period_2    |period    |period    |period    |
-----------------------------------------------
|period_2    |period    |period    |period    |
-----------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sort of missing the point of `mysql_fetch_assoc()` and rows in MySQL:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo $row['index_period'];
  echo $row['index_period_1'];
  echo $row['index_period_2'];
}
```

You call `mysql_fetch_assoc()` *once* per row.

---

I'm not really sure *why* you need to loop over your table like this, but I won't interrogate you.

This might fit your needs (I cringe writing this):

```
$index_period = array();
$index_period_1 = array();
$index_period_2 = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $index_period[] = $row['index_period'];
  $index_period_1[] = $row['index_period_1'];
  $index_period_2[] = $row['index_period_2'];
}

foreach ($index_period as $value) {
  echo "<td>a" . $value . "</td>";
}

foreach ($index_period_1 as $value) {
  echo "<td>b" . $value . "</td>";
}

foreach ($index_period_2 as $value) {
  echo "<td>c" . $value . "</td>";
}
```

Comment: I can't do this way. It must help to generate html table. I must receive $field[], $field_1[] and $field_2[] in 3 ways.

Comment: How is my code different from yours? I just omitted the `<td>` tags.

Comment: @Andrew: This is how `mysql_fetch_assoc` works.  You loop though your results via rows, not fields.  You can make 3 arrays (or one 2D array), and put each field into its respective array, then loop through those and make your table.

Comment: @Blender: Seems he was trying to loop over each field, not each row.

Comment: @Rocket: So he is trying to loop over columns? I'll see how I can help.

Comment: @Blender: My suggestion may work.  Loop though rows, save each field in an array, loop though arrays to make table.

Comment: well - from query I've 4 rows with 5 cols each. I try to display first in one table row column (months), after in rows rest of data. Than I try to loop 3 times the same query result to take the data.

Comment: @Blender - your solution is perfect (second part :)) ), thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Once you finish your first for loop, you have iterated through the entire result set. So when you enter your next for loop, there is nothing left to iterate and `mysql_fetch_assoc()` returns false. If you want to reset the internal data pointer, you can call

```
mysql_data_seek($result, 0);
```

This will enable you to re-iterate through the result set in your next for loop.

Comment: @Andrew No problem. Though you might look into the info that @Blender and @Rocket are mentioning, just to grasp the concepts of iterating through result sets using `mysql_fetch_assoc`. GL